# AdMob/Android : no requests at all

Tags: android, admob

All of a sudden, my Android app doesn't display any AdMob ad. I don't see any error message in LogCat when running my app with ad test mode disabled. And I can't see any "ad request" message (but may be there isn't such log trace). In the AdMob website dashboard, the number of ad requests seems to be frozen.

Do you how one can see what the AdMob server respond to the Android app when it request for an add? There might be some request answer, like "wrong publisher id", "account suspended" (I don't think it is as I didn't received any mail)...

Comment: Make sure you're using the most recent AdMob SDK. Newer versions could be backward incompatible, especially if you use AdMob together with AdWhirl

Comment: I am using the latest version and only AdMob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a glitch in AdMob since everything is fine today. Thanks for your time.